# Google maps height only 30px

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a web app with jQuery Mobile.
My map doesn't show the way I want.
I would like it to fill the screen under the header.
The width and height of the content div are set to 100% but only the width follows this parameter, the height sets itself to 30px.

This page is shown when a button is clicked:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="Map">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#Resultaten" data-role="button" data-icon="back" align="left" 
        data-iconshadow="false" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide"
        data-iconpos="notext">Terug</a>
        <h1>Kaart</h1>
        <a href="#Home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" 
        data-iconshadow="false" data-direction="reverse" onclick="empty()" 
        data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="notext">Terug</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="map_canvas">
    <script>
        var map;
        function create_map(){
            var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);    
        }                

    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css of map_canvas:

```
.map_canvas{
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
padding: 0;
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map_canvas` will not have any effect to an element with the ID `map_canvas` , use `#map_canvas` instead

Comment: Yes little mistake, thank you for your clear eye but it doesn't solve it completely.

Answer (score 0):

CSS needs to know 100% of *something*. Currently you haven't specified a height for the `div` which contains your map `div`. In desktop browsers it's necessary to specify the height all the way up the heirarchy to `<html>`.

It's also not good practice to put anything inside the map `div` yourself as the API needs that space. You may find the API removes your script when it creates the map.

Comment: Ok I placed my script tag above the map `div`.
`html, body { height: 100%; }` does not work

Comment: How about the `div id="Map"`?

Comment: When I set the width and height of the `div id ="Map"` to 100% the result is better ONLY in combination with the `div id="map_canvas"` also set to 100%.
I now get a scroll-bar to scroll down the same height as the header.
I also get a buggy map with only 10% displayed and when I re-size my browser the map appears normal.

Comment: That's because you haven't specified a height for the header. Browsers are not particularly intelligent, although they can make some good guesses. Generally you need to tell them *exactly* what they need to do with *everything*.

Comment: but isn't jQuery mobile taking care of that ?